# CSS variable defined with !important flag disappears in angular production mode

Tags: css, angular, css-variables

I have an issue with CSS variable (defined using `var()` syntax) with `!important` flag disappearing when Angular project is build in production mode (using `ng build --prod`). Specifically, in my `scss` file I have something like this:

```
.all-borders {
  border: 3px solid var(--primary) !important;
  // in "development" build this is correctly compiled to:  "border:1px solid var(--primary)!important"
  // in "production" build this is incorrectly compiled to: "border:1px solid!important"
}

.window {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

and in `html` file I have defined a simple `div` element like this:

```
<div class="all-borders window"></div>
```

and when I run `ng serve` (so build in `dev` mode) I can see that border is correctly compiled and applied on my `div` element. But, when I build in `prod` mode then my border becomes black and I can see in inspector that style has been compiled to `border: 1px solid!important` (notice that `var(...)` disappeared).

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6utmv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) example demonstrating this issue (that is *development* version) and [here](https://test-border-right-css-vars.firebaseapp.com/) is how this looks when build for *production* and deployed.

The question is, can anyone explain to me why is this happening?

I can fix this issue in multiple ways, for example reorganizing styles and removing `!important`, or even writing *border* style like this `border: var(--primary) 1px solid !important` (weirdly enough, this works fine), but I am wondering why is this happening, could it be just a bug or is there a universal reason behind this?

Comment: _Additionally_, I could only reproduce this issue with `border` shorthand property (so `border-color: var(--primary)!important` works just fine) so this sounds more and more like a bug to me...

Comment: you can always try to report it as a bug and see

Comment: Yeah, I was planning on doing that, but first I figured I'll ask here and see if anyone else has this kind of a problem...

Comment: Hey @miselking you should make your edit an answer instead; it's valid.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I added it as an answer now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an issue on Angular repo [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/34561), and it seems that this is a bug and will be fixed in Angular v9.

From what I could find out it seems that the issue was in the [CSS optimizer](https://github.com/jakubpawlowicz/clean-css/issues/1060) they used, so they switched to a [different one](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano) and it seems the issue is resolved (in v9). Worst case scenario is that this may introduce some breaking changes in which case this fix may not make it in v9 but there are no indications that this will happen (for now).